# Drawing sprites in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

I get a NullPoinerExecption when calling

```
enemy.getSprite().draw(batch);
```

Where do I have to initialize my sprite? 
It works in main class, but if I try to initialize texture and sprite in Enemy constructor then it gives me error.

Here's my **main class**:

```
  public class SpaceShooter implements ApplicationListener {

     private SpriteBatch batch;
        private Texture texture;
        private Sprite sprite, spriteEnemy;
        private Player p;
        private Enemy enemy;

        @Override
        public void create() {       
            p = new Player();
            enemy = new Enemy(spriteEnemy);


            float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

            batch = new SpriteBatch();

            texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("craft.png"));
            sprite = new Sprite(texture);
            sprite.setPosition(w/2 -sprite.getWidth()/2, h/2 - sprite.getHeight()/2);

            // Adding enemy sprite

        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            batch.dispose();
            texture.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void render() {        
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // moving sprite left and right


            batch.begin();
            sprite.draw(batch);
            enemy.getSprite().draw(batch);          
            batch.end();
        }
```

**Enemy class**

```
 public class Enemy {

    private Sprite sprite;
    private Texture texture;


    boolean gameOver;

    public Enemy(Sprite sprite){

        this.sprite = new Sprite();

    }

    public Sprite getSprite(){
        return sprite;
    }

    public void create() {
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("enemy.png"));
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        this.sprite.setPosition(100, 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never called `create()` on your Enemy instance, so the texture and sprite in Enemy are never instantiated.  Call `enemy.create()` in your `create()` method. Or simplify things and move the code in `enemy.create()` into the Enemy constructor.

Also, in your Enemy constructor, you are instantiating a useless Sprite instance that does not reference a Texture and which will be thrown away once `create()` is called on the enemy. And the constructor does not even use the Sprite reference that's passed in (although you are currently just passing in `null` anyway because `spriteEnemy` in the SpaceShooter class is never instantiated).

Comment: calling an enemy.create() fixed the problem.

Comment: Also moved all my code to Player and Enemy constructors. Thanks for help!